# jQuery scroll along x-axis: improve performance?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this bit of script here that takes some position:absolute elems and scrolls them along the x-axis only. It works but is super slow. Any way to speed up the performance?

```
  (function() {
  var $menu = $('.gallery-nav ul'),
     $headA = $("header .home"),
     leftOffset1 = parseInt($menu.css('left')),
     leftOffset2 = parseInt($headA.css('left'));

  $(window).scroll(function(){
     $menu.css({
       'left': $(this).scrollLeft() + leftOffset1
     });
     $headA.css({
       'left': $(this).scrollLeft() + leftOffset2 
     });
   });
 })();
```

UPDATE: http://jsfiddle.net/davidpm/LeTEX/2/

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle, where we can play around a bit together? ;)

Comment: side note: I'd love it if we could use the native style object (since that would speed things up), but I'm not too familiar with pure JS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your approach here since there is a perfect and very very speedy way only using CSS for that task.
You can simply set your element's position to `fixed` which means that they'll STAY AT THE POSITION regardless of document width/height or scrolling.

```
myElement{ position: fixed; left: 0; }
```

See [DA new FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LeTEX/1/)

Comment: if you need animation of this menu you have to change how your code works with timeout-timers and animation. if so - please gimme a notice and don't downvote my answer ;)

Comment: I simply don't want the elements to scroll along the y-axis. position: fixed forces you to do both. I only want to scroll horizontally. The fiddle doesn't demonstrate it, but the real site is much longer along the y-axis.

Comment: get that but i can't attest "terrible slowiness" to your initial jsfiddle? are you sure the problem is in this script? you're doing no heavy operations in here

Comment: there is just some lag between the header and nav on the real deal. I'm not sure why.

Comment: ah! i possible know why - the 'scroll'-event is not fired on EVERY pixel-move... it's only in some predifined distances called or when you stop scrolling... possible you should use the "fixed"-technique and animate the scrolling on the Y-AXIS of the element when scrolling down. (looks better i think)